# Symfony/Sonata - How to display a calculated value in list & edit action

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

My admin has to handle bookings, each booking have a price that depend of many parameters (like room, week, participant...) and so it's calculated (not in my Entity).

I would like to display this price during list, edit & show action. For exemple my list action could display a table like:

> lastname | firstname | **price**

My question is how can I create in my Admin class a new field and get his computed value from a Admin class method or an action of a controller?

Comment: Just found my solution explain for a different problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140717/sonata-admin-custom-list-field-not-from-entity

Comment: Could you share your answer if you found a way to calculate field?